# Nodejs, Express + Angular POST 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am working on my MEAN stack (mySQL not MongoDB and I am also using the EJS templating engine) application and I am running into a problem with posting data into my MySQL DB. As the title says I am getting a '404' error in my console which I think indicates that the post method cannot be found. If I putt the method in the server file, the post does work but I get a message saying 'invalid json'.

Anyone has any ideas as to why this is happening?

My current code is listed as below. I am a beginner in any of this so I would really appreciate well explained answers as that is the best way to learn where it went wrong.

Server/app:

```
> var express = require('express'); var path = require('path'); //var
> favicon = require('serve-favicon'); var logger = require('morgan');
> var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); var bodyParser =
> require('body-parser'); var http = require('http');
> 
> var mysql = require('mysql');
> 
> var app = express();
> 
> var port = 1337;
> 
> // view engine setup app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
> app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
> 
> // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
> //app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
> app.use(logger('dev')); app.use(bodyParser.json());
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
> app.use(cookieParser());
> app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
> app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
> app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname +
> '/bower_components'));
> 
> var clientRoute = require('./routes/clientConfig.js');
> 
> new clientRoute(app);
> 
> app.use(require('./server/Dao/clientDao.js'));
> 
> module.exports = app;
> 
> app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1337);
> http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
>     console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port')); });
```

Angular controller:

```
> var clientModule = angular.module('clientModule', []);
> 
> clientModule.controller('clientController', ['$scope', '$http',
> function ($scope, $http) {
>     console.log("Hello world from controller");
>     
>     $scope.addClient = function () {
>         console.log($scope.client);
>         
>         $http.post('/createClient', $scope.client).success(function(response) {
>             console.log(response);
>         })
>     } }]);
```

Server-side post (I have no idea but it seems that it does not reference well to my server folder):

```
>  var express = require('express'); var router = express.Router(); var
> connectionProvider = require('../mysqlConnectionStringProvider.js');
> 
> router.post('/createClient', function (req, res) {
>     console.log(req.body); 
>     
>     var connection = connectionProvider.mysqlConnectionStringProvider.getMySqlConnection();
> 
>     var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Clients SET?"
>     
>     var client = { 
>         clientName : req.body.client.clientName, // this should be req.body.client.clientName 
>         clientAddress : req.body.client.clientAddress // this should be req.body.client.clientAddress 
>     }
> 
>      
>     if (connection) {
>         connection.query(insertStatement, client, function (err, result) {
> 
>             if (err) {
>                 console.log(err);
>             }
> 
>             //console.log(result);
>         });
>     }
>     connectionProvider.mysqlConnectionStringProvider.closeMySqlConnection(connection);
> });
> 
> router.get('/createClient', function (req, res) {
>     
>     res.render('clients/createClient.ejs', {title : 'Add client'}); }) 
> 
> module.exports = router;
```

Html:

```html
<% include ../layout %>

    <div class="container" ng-app="clientModule" ng-controller="clientController">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="/createClient" method="post" name="formClient">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="">Client name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter client name" name="clientName" ng-model="client.clientName" style="width: 100%" required>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="">Client address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter client address" name="clientName" ng-model="client.clientAddress" style="width: 100%" required>
                    <p>{{client.clientAddress}}</p>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp;</div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addClient()">Create client</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="./controllers/clients/clientController.js"></script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So  what is the problem? The row is not inserted? Do you face any errors?

Comment: The post is not working. I am getting a '404 error' which (I think) indicates that the post is not called. I just don't know where the mistake is made..

Sorry for the bad explanation. I have edited my post.

Comment: I see a few typos, in your html you have `ng-model="clients.clientName"` notice **clients** and in your controller `console.log($scope.client);` notice **client** and in `$http.post('/createClient', $scope.createClient` you passing the function `createClient` to server, what you want is to pass $scope.client but first change that in html, this should fix the `I get a message saying 'invalid json'`. And I'm not sure what ` app.exports ` is supposed to do? I believe it should be `module.exports`

Comment: To require a file with routes use `require('./routes/clientConfig.js')(app);` and the file would look like `module.exports = function(app){ app.get(...);}` no `Router` needed, well there's obviously reason for `Router` but you don't need to use it. what i'm showing is one of the ways.

Comment: Thanks @Molda for the pointers! I got the 'post' function to work within my server file. 

How do I get it to work within another folder? I feel that I have to reference the 'app' inside that file so that it knows how to run 'express' etcetera. I just have no idea how to make that reference?

Comment: My 2nd comment explains how to do that. In your Server/app use `require('routes.js')(app);` <-- the app reference is passed to routes.js. And in your routes.js use `module.exports = function(app){ // use app here same way as in the Server/app app.post(...)}`

Comment: What you already have is actually almost right. Instead of `app.exports` use `var router = express.Router(); router.post(...); module.exports = router;` and in Server/app `app.use(require('routes.js'); ` So there's more ways to achieve the same.

Comment: @Molda thank you so much! I ended up using the 'router' and I am thinking of converint my jQuery routing to some other routing. 

In this project would you advice continuing with express routing or with angular routing?

Also could you add your answer as an answer so I can up-vote it and mark it as the correct answer :)? I don't want to take away any of your credits!

Comment: I'll add my answer whem im on my pc. I use angular and $stateProvider for routing which works good for me and if you already use angular on client then using it also for routing makes sense. I never used jQuery for routing so can't tell which is better. No matter what you use on client you still need express routing for serving main page, api, login, logout etc. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed my code and I got my SQL to work. So if I hard code my client with strings then it works. However using Angular it still does not work since it's saying 'client.clientName is undefined'.

Do you have any idea as to why this is happening?

Comment: In the clientController i can't see $scope.client, have you defined it?

Comment: No? Where should I define it?

Comment: What is the output of console.log($scope.client); in your clientController when you click addClient?

Comment: I actually get an error saying 'typeError: cannot read property 'clientName' of undefined.

Comment: in clientController add $scope.client = { clientName:'', clientAddress: '' }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96057/discussion-between-mick-and-molda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use routes from another file you can do following

routes/clientConfig.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get(...); 
router.post(...); 
router.put(...); 

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
...
app.use(require('./routes/clientConfig.js'));
...
```